# What is the basic concept behind WaitHandle?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

What is the basic concept behind `WaitHandle` in C# .net threading?
Whats is its use?
When to use it?
What is the use of **WaitAll** and **WaitAny** methods inside it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Whenever you would want to control the execution of multiple threads in your app. Though this does not only mean that only one thread increments the counter; but let the threads start/stop or pause upon an event.

See [WaitHandles - Auto/ManualResetEvent and Mutex](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/waithandles.shtml)

**--EDIT--**

`WaitHandle`s are the *mechanism* that you "use" to control the threads' execution. Its not about handles not being accessible within a thread; its about using them within the thread.

This may be a fat example, but please bear with me; think about, a lady gives five different toned whistles to five girls, and tells them to blow the whistle whenever `something` would happen; the process is for each girl to blow a whistle, and the lady would know who blew the whistle.

Now, its not about sharing-the-whistles with each other, its about, probably for the lady, to use them to "control" the execution or the process how girls would blow the whistle.

Therefore, technically the process would be to:

1. Create a wait event(ManualResetEvent object)
2. Register the events, `WaitHandle.WaitAny(events);`
3. After you are done performing operation in your thread, the `.Set()`, which would tell the WaitHandle that 'I am done!'.

For instance, consider the example from the link provided. I have added the steps for you to understand the logic. These aren't the hardcoded steps, but just so you may understand.

```
class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
    //STEP 1: Create a wait handle
        ManualResetEvent[] events = new ManualResetEvent[10];//Create a wait handle
        for (int i=0; i < events.Length; i++)
        {
            events[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            Runner r = new Runner(events[i], i); 
            new Thread(new ThreadStart(r.Run)).Start();
        }

    //STEP 2: Register for the events to wait for
        int index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(events); //wait here for any event and print following line.

        Console.WriteLine ("***** The winner is {0} *****", 
                           index);

        WaitHandle.WaitAll(events); //Wait for all of the threads to finish, that is, to call their cooresponding `.Set()` method.

        Console.WriteLine ("All finished!");
    }
}


class Runner
{
    static readonly object rngLock = new object();
    static Random rng = new Random();

    ManualResetEvent ev;
    int id;

    internal Runner (ManualResetEvent ev, int id)
    {
        this.ev = ev;//Wait handle associated to each object, thread in this case.
        this.id = id;
    }

    internal void Run()
    {
    //STEP 3: Do some work
        for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            int sleepTime;
            // Not sure about the thread safety of Random...
            lock (rngLock)
            {
                sleepTime = rng.Next(2000);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(sleepTime);
            Console.WriteLine ("Runner {0} at stage {1}",
                               id, i);
        }

    //STEP 4: Im done!
        ev.Set();
    }
}
```

Comment: WaitAll() - used to wait for all of the handles in a set to be free/signalled... Does it mean that Handles will not be accessible to other threads untill and unless they are not released(other threads should wait for these handles in the set) ?

Comment: @DotNetBeginner: `Does it mean that Handles will not be accessible to other threads`; please see my updated post, an example added just to respond to this question.

Comment: it is worth saying that `ev.Set()` better to be put in the `finally` block

Comment: Why's it gotta be a lady "controlling" girls when we're talking whistles? Maybe kangaroos given whistles by a wallaby or something?

Comment: ruffin: Because it had to be something. Kangaroos and wallabies aren't any better, especially since they're not commonly known to blow whistles.

Answer (score 36):

`WaitHandle` is an abstract base class for the two commonly used event handles: `AutoResetEvent` and `ManualResetEvent`.

Both of these classes allow one thread to "signal" one or more other threads. They're used to synchronize (or serialize activity) between threads. This is accomplished using the `Set` and `WaitOne` (or `WaitAll`) methods. For example:

Thread 1:

```
// do setup work

myWaitHandle.Set();
```

Thread 2:

```
// do setup work

myWaitHandle.WaitOne();

// this code will not continue until after the call to `Set` 
// in thread 1 completes.
```

This is a very rudimentary example, and there are loads of them available on the web. The basic idea is that `WaitOne` is used to wait for a signal from another thread that indicates that *something* has happened. In the case of `AsyncWaitHandle` (which is returned from invoking a delegate asynchronously), `WaitOne` allows you to cause the current thread to wait until the async operation has completed.

When an `AutoResetEvent` or `ManualResetEvent` are not set, calls to `WaitOne` will block the calling thread until `Set` is called. These two classes differ only in that `AutoResetEvent` "unsets" the event once a successful call to `WaitOne` completes, making subsequent calls block again until `Set` is called. `ManualResetEvent` must be "unset" explicitly by calling `Reset`.

`WaitAll` and `WaitAny` are static methods on the `WaitHandle` class that allow you to specify an array of `WaitHandles` to wait on. `WaitAll` will block until *all* of the supplied handles are `Set`, whereas `WaitAny` will only block until *one* of them gets `Set`.

Answer (score 10):

It is an abstract class, you don't use it directly.  Concrete derived classes are ManualResetEvent, AutoResetEvent, Mutex and Semaphore.  Important classes in your toolbox to implement thread synchronization.  They inherit the WaitOne, WaitAll and WaitAny methods, you use them to detect that one or more threads signaled the wait condition.

Typical usage scenario for Manual/AutoResetEvent is to tell a thread to exit or to let a thread signal that it has progressed to an important sequence point.  Semaphore helps you to limit the number of threads that perform an action.  Or to implement threading synchronization that should not have affinity to a particular thread.  Mutex is there to assign ownership to a section of code to one thread, the lock statement is often applicable there as well.

Books have been written about it.  Joe Duffy's [Concurrent Programming in Windows](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/032143482X) is the latest and greatest.  Strongly recommended if you contemplate writing threaded code.

Answer (score 8):

Imagine you have an array with 1000 items in it. You need to do some processing on every one of those items. This work will take some time, but is not I/O bound.

For example, maybe you need to use each item to make a low-bandwidth web request. You have plenty of throughput to request many items at the same time, and the latency in each web request means doing one at a time could take longer than you want.

Enter the world of parallel programming. Today there are a number of ways you can handle this task, and `WaitHandle` is a fundamental part of it. Even if you don't use a `WaitHandle` directly, whatever option you choose is likely relying on a `WaitHandle` such as `WaitAll` or `WaitAny` behind the scenes.

Continuing the example, let's say you have a typical four-core CPU. In this situation, it doesn't make a lot of sense to have more than 4 threads going at once.<sup>*</sup> So 4 threads, but 1000 items;  what do you do?

One option uses `WaitAny`. You kick off 4 threads, and every time the `WaitAny` method returns you kick off another, until all 1000 items are queued. Note this is a poor example for `WaitAny`, because we know how many items there in total and can access any of the items at the same rate. `WaitAny` is best when you only have sequential access. There are other, similar situations where `WaitAny` can make a lot of sense.

Another option uses `WaitAll`. Instead of queuing one item at a time, you set up one thread for each of the four cores assign it a different 250 item segment of the array.  With this option, you can use `WaitAll` to wait for all the processing to finish.

---

<sub>* Actually, it does. There's usually a certain amount of I/O time where the CPU would be idle, such that you can do better by having more than one thread going per core. But that's a story for another time.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

There are some very long answers here. For anyone looking for the short answer:

Wait handle are a mechanism for making one thread wait until another thread reaches a certain point.

You can also have several threads waiting and/or several threads that are being waited for, hence the `WaitOne`, `WaitAll` and `WaitAny` methods. There are also several options for semantics available by choosing one of these classes: `Mutex`, `Semaphore`, `ManualResetEvent`, `AutoResetEvent` which are well documented.