# Controlling background task instances

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, synchronization, windows-8.1-universal

Is there any way to synchronize several instances of one background task?

I'm working on a universal windows 8.1 store project. I have a background task that receives raw notifications and downloads and updates some data (hopefully meeting the CPU quota and running time limitations).

I want to avoid running background work simultaneously on Windows Phone when several pushes arrive at once. That is, background task should check if another instance of it is running and exit quietly.

The only way I could think of was through a semaphore file in local storage... But since all file IO on WP is asynchronous, I don't see how I could get it working without race conditions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking only about WP8.1 or also W10? - you tagged [tag:uwp] which stands for W10.

Comment: Well, they used to call it Universal Store Application for Windows 8.1. Ok, I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are objects for cross-process synchronization and using them is much better that signaling with a file. You may think of using [EventWaithHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hw29w7t1(v=vs.110).aspx) with name for global synchronization. It can work among multiple processes (not only threads). A good example of this synchronization you can find [at Alabhari's blog](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Signaling_with_Event_Wait_Handles).

In your case if the handle is set then it means that other process if performing work and current one can return.

As for waithandles you may find more information at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2538065/2681948).

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know EventWaithHandle works between processes. A question though: what happens if OS kills the process that locked EventWaithHandle before it had a chance to signal?

Comment: So, to use this technique I do the following: `bool createNew; var handle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "bglock", out createNew);`; if createNew flag is up, then I have just locked "bglock" system event, otherwise other process is holding it at the moment and I should exit. Am I getting this right?

Comment: Will this approach rely on me disposing the EventWaitHandle when the work is complete? This may not happen at all, because OS may kill my process at any moment without even firing an event at me or something. With files I at least could check the time semaphore file was created to detect a stale lock.

Comment: @NoxNoctis Note that when OS cancels your BTask, then it gets *Cancelled* event and *Completed* one - you should handle this situation. As for patterns you can take a look here for [good mutex pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/229567/2681948) - it can be probably simplified in your case, but should be a good start. Basicly as I think, you create a global object then run *bool hasHandle = obj.WaitHandle(0)* if has handle then perform some work and after finish release mutex. There can be some pitfalls - remember that synchronization object must be returned by the same thread it was acquired.

Comment: The reference says "If an out of memory exception is not surfaced, or the app does not handle it, then the background task will be terminated without warning and without raising the OnCanceled event."

Comment: @NoxNoctis Then it means that you should handle memory exception in your background task. When you use global synchronization objects then you need to handle all exception - do not leave abandoned synchronization object.